# I cant import System.Directory when using stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am little confused about why this doesn't work.

I have a small program that import System.Directory. When I run it with runhaskell on the command line it compiles and outputs what I expect.

When I use the same program with stack I get a message saying

> Failed to load interface for ‘System.Directory’
>       It is a member of the hidden package ‘directory-1.3.0.0’.
>       Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

I dont understand why it would work with `runhaskell` but not when i use `stack ghci`

Comment: Stack doesn't use your os environment. You have just to add `direcotry` into `build-depends` section in cabal file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the information you give, I can only attempt a guess…

I think you have `directory` (globally) installed with `cabal install directory` or as a system package - this would explain `runhaskell myscript.hs` working.

if you use `stack` you have the following options.

1. make a cabal package, add `directory` to the build depends section, create a `stack.yaml` and run `stack ghci` inside the project directory.
2. use `stack ghci --package=directory myscript.hs`

Comment: I looked at `ghc-pkg list` I guess that is all of the packages that are installed that runhaskell would use? I didn't realize all of that was there. Thanks!