# Can't import System.Directory when using stack to load a file in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

I checked [I cant import System.Directory when using stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260461/i-cant-import-system-directory-when-using-stack?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but I think I'm the different case.

Just like case above, it worked well with `runhaskell`, but when I retried it with `stack ghci` I got error saying:

```
C:\haskell\Hello\app\Main.hs:3:1: error:
Could not find module ‘System.Directory’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Why it works when I use `runhaskell` but not `stack ghci`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the [`directory`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.2.2/docs/System-Directory.html) package in your stack.yaml like the post you link to suggests?

Comment: @hnefatl This page does not say to use `package.yaml` over `stack.yaml`.

Comment: Given the directory structure you mention, I suppose you have a Stack-managed project (as opposed to, say, trying to load an isolated file in `stack ghci`). From which directory are you running `stack ghci`? I believe that, in this use case, you should run it from the root of your project (i.e. where `stack.yaml` is).

Answer (score 1):

Consider `stack ghci --package directory`?  What's going on is that `stack runhaskell` will see all the packages in your DB - it doesn't use package hiding.  This means its behavior varies depending on what's already been installed.

`stack ghci`, on the other hand, defaults to hiding all the packages unless they are in the dependencies of the current targets.  If there are no targets, you can add additional dependencies via the `--package` option.